# Make top-level index entry bold within a macro

Tags: indexing

I created an index in which some entries have subentries: for those kind of entries I created `\ati` macro, while for entries without subentries I use another macro.

In those entries created by `\ati` macro I want top-level entry to be bold. I was able to get what I want without a macro with "Entry":

[image: Index entry with bold formatting]

However I am unable to achieve the same with the macro **without changing number of arguments**. I want this macro to have only two arguments, in that order, because I use it in existing document.

I think the way to achieve this is to somehow process text before and after first exclamation mark (`!`) in first argument and then somehow incorporate that into macro definition without changing amount of arguments. But I have no idea how to go about that.

(In case it is important to solution, I use `texindy` as index processor.)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{splitidx}
\makeindex
\def \ati#1#2{#2\index{#1}} % "Add to index" macro
\begin{document}
\blindtext

There are many ways to write a document. You could use a \ati{Markup!LaTeX@\LaTeX}{\LaTeX}, \ati{Markup!Markdown}{Markdown} or even \ati{Markup!HTML}{HTML}. If you do write your document by hand, do not use \ati{Markup!XML}{XML}, because you are going to go mad.

\blindtext[5]

\ati{Markup!LaTeX@\LaTeX}{\LaTeX} is obviously the best to produce high-quality PDF file, but you do not have to type it by hand. You can use \ati{Markup!Markdown}{Markdown} instead and then convert it to both \ati{Markup!HTML}{HTML} and \ati{Markup!LaTeX@\LaTeX}{\LaTeX}, as well as many other formats.

Now comes interesting stuff. When you write a technical book in \ati{Markup!LaTeX@\LaTeX}{\LaTeX}, you can quite easily create an \sindex{Index creation}index. When you do, you have quite a few choices when it comes to packages you use and \ati{Index processor}{index processors} that will sort your .idx file into .ind file that gets included in your document at the time of next compilation.

\blindtext[6]

One of those index processors is \ati{Index processor!MakeIndex}{MakeIndex}, but there are also few other alternatives. I personally prefer to use \ati{Index processor!xindy}{xindy} through command line program called texindy.

\pagebreak

Now, I want to make each top-level entry like ``Index processor'' and ``Markup'' bold, only for those entries which do have sub-entries (this is what \\ati macro is for). It would be awesome if I could use same macro even for entries which do not have subentries and still get bold top-level entries only for those entries with subentries, but it is not must-have.

So what I want to produce looks like this:

\index{Entry@\textbf{Entry}}{entry}

\index{Entry@\textbf{Entry}!subentry}{subentry}
\index{Entry@\textbf{Entry}!subentry!subsubentry}{subentry}

\index{Entry@\textbf{Entry}!another entry}{another entry}

\index{Entry@\textbf{Entry}!another entry}{another entry}

\index{Entry@\textbf{Entry}!yet another entry}{yet another entry}

but I want to achieve it inside ``ati'' macro.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Is this at all possible?